# JS script dynamic loading inconsitent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loading

I need help on getting some dynamic js loading working properly. the issue I'm having now is that it is not consistently loading the js script when loading the page. here is the script that I have at the bottom of the page that I'm opening:

```
function getJSOnload() {
    var element;
    var parent = document.body;
    var cdn = [
                LoadFormValidationScript(LoginFormValidator),
                LoadFormValidationScript(SetFormLocaleLang)
            ];
    var i = 0, file;
    for (i;i<cdn.length;i++) {
        file = cdn[i];
        element = document.createElement("script");
        element.type = "text/javascript";
        element.src  = file;
        parent.appendChild(element);
        //free file's value
        file = null;
    }
};
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("load", getJSOnload(), false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onload", getJSOnload());
    }
    else window.onload = getJSOnload();
```

this is the LoadFormValidationScript that i have in an external js file

```
function LoadFormValidationScript(callback){

    function LoadValidationScripts() {

        $.getScript('/plugins/script1.min.js', function() {
            $.getScript('/plugins/script2.min.js', function() {
                $.getScript('/plugins/script3.addons.min.js', function() {
                    $.getScript('/plugins/script.es_ES.js', function() {
                        $.getScript('/plugins/script4.fr_FR.js', function() {
                            $.getScript('/plugins/script5.de_DE.js', callback);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
    if (!$.fn.formValidation){
        LoadValidationScripts();
    } else {
        if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
            callback();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the "setFormLocaleLang" function as an example since it is short one

```
function SetFormLocaleLang(){

    var nberOfForm = document.forms.length; //get number of forms on the page

    // if there are no forms in the page don't waist your time
    if (nberOfForm > 0) {
        var Locale = "en_US"; //default formVlaidation language
        //var lang =  $('html').attr('lang'); // get the page language
        var lang = $("#selectedLanguage").attr('data-lang-id');

       // assign the Locale depending on page language
        switch (lang) {
            case "en" : Locale = 'en_US'; break;
            case "fr" : Locale = 'fr_FR'; break;
            case "es" : Locale = 'es_ES'; break;
            case "de" : Locale = 'de_DE'; break;
            default : break;
        };
        //set the locale for all the forms in the page
        for (var i = 0; i < nberOfForm; i++) {
            var strFormID = "#" + document.forms[i].id;
            $(strFormID).formValidation('setLocale', Locale);
        }
    }
}
```

like is said it does work and load the scripts but not all the time, sometimes i have to refresh the page like 3 time for the script to load and sometimes it loads on the first try as soon as i open the page. not sure what is going on and why i get this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attaching the handlers incorrectly - you're calling `getJSOnload()` immediately, instead of waiting for document-loaded, as you intend. Reference, don't call, the function:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", getJSOnload, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", getJSOnload);
}
else window.onload = getJSOnload;
```

Comment: I made the change and still getting the same behavior.